# UI.Component is undefined error

Tags: javascript, meteor

This error looks like something is simply not defined.  Not sure exactly what I need to define or how.  Anybody got any ideas?

```
TypeError: UI.Component is undefined (
line 132 of blaze-layout.js:  Layout = UI.Component.extend({  )

Exception in defer callback: IronRouter<.autoRender@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?a4167ac4d12a73891d8a9b8c57419a347da0ee12:1579:7
IronRouter<.constructor/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?a4167ac4d12a73891d8a9b8c57419a347da0ee12:1424:11
.withValue@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?7a66be7a03504cd2c18dd47b699e6233b60675ed:793:11
withoutInvocation/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?7a66be7a03504cd2c18dd47b699e6233b60675ed:382:26
Meteor.bindEnvironment/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?7a66be7a03504cd2c18dd47b699e6233b60675ed:821:11
onGlobalMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?7a66be7a03504cd2c18dd47b699e6233b60675ed:319:11
```

Thanks in advance for any tips on sorting this!

Comment: What version of meteor are you running?  Is this relevant: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2374

Comment: $ meteor --version  
Release 0.8.3

Comment: $ meteor list --using  
standard-app-packages  
autopublish  
insecure  
less  
less-bootstrap-3  
font-awesome-4-less  
accounts-password  
accounts-ui  
accounts-entry  
accounts-twitter

Comment: the only ui package I'm using is accounts-ui .... wonder if that's the culprit.

Comment: judging by the error message, it is obvious that you are running iron-router in your app. Update iron-router and that should work fine.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  The current version is 0.8.2 and when I try updating I get this:

✓ iron-router
    tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git#v0.7.0

Comment: This perhaps some dependency problem on the blaze-layout package?  I tried removing the version number from smart.json but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Have you tried `mrt update`?

Comment: Yup, tried that and no change :(